# parameterised routing in jekyll

Tags: routes, jekyll

I am using jekyll to code my static site, I want the behaviour of route params inside there.
e.g.,
My route could be `showInfo/:id` where id is variable and can be used by the JS to fetch some data specific to the `id` provided.

The page snippet below:

```
---
layout: showProfile
title: Show Profile Info
permalink: user/:id
language: en
display-title: "false"
list: exclude
---

## User Profile
```

While I thought this to work, it actually doesn't.
It only shows the HTML page linked, if I go to the route: "user/:id", instead I wanted to work it as a paramterised route and show the page if I provide anything like: `user/123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jekyll is interpreting your user:/id as a string. I am not sure what variable stores your userids, maybe trying `{{ userid }}`, substituting userid with the relevant variable name. In any case you can set the permalink structure globally as described here https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/

I suggest you start from there

Comment: Thanks Andrea, I think I overlooked the concept of permalinks in the first go, your answer enforced me to give a deep thought